# SQLite C# Simple Database lookup

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have inserted a lot of information into a SQlite database from my program. Now, my small task is to look up the database and find some statistics from it.

Ex: I have a database with three fields - Timestamp, Message and Key
Now, I want to check the database in the Message column and count the number of times a certain keyword(say "ERROR") occurs in the database.

What is the simplest way to do this? 
SELECT Message from Database and how do i add the filter???

I use Regex to filter out some stuff before Insert. Should i do something similar here?

Thanks

Edit:

I used the solution mentioned below SELECT count(*) but am still unaware of how to get the value out to use it in another function. I have shown the code i used below. I am new to SQL and it possibly is wrong. Please help!

```
public void selectFromDatabase()
    {
        String cntnStr_query = "data source=C:\\TMU_Files\\test31.s3db";
        SQLiteConnection connection_query = new SQLiteConnection(cntnStr_query);
        connection_query.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd_query = connection_query.CreateCommand();
        cmd_query.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from LogDatabase where LogMessage like '%ERR%'";
        SQLiteDataAdapter da_query = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd_query);
        DataSet ds_query = new DataSet();
        //MessageBox.Show(cmd_query.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
        try
        {
            da_query.Fill(ds_query);
            DataTable dt_query = ds_query.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd_query.Dispose();
            connection_query.Close();
        }
        //cmd_query.Dispose();
        //connection_query.Close();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: just for clarity - number of times error appears or the number of rows it appears in?

Comment: the number of rows it appears in..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select count(*) from database where message like '%error%'
```

As to how it should look like in code, try something like this:

```
using(var sda=new SQLiteDataAdapter(
  "SELECT count(*) from LogDatabase where LogMessage like '%ERR%'",
  "data source=C:\\TMU_Files\\test31.s3db")
{
  var dt=new DataTable();
  sda.Fill(dt);
  return dt;
}
```

Comment: what is count here? the column?

Comment: `count` returns the number of rows in the query.

Comment: is there a way to get the value of count into some variable back in C# for me to use it for other stuff?  Like where is stored once calculated?

Comment: In the resulting DataTable (if you call `SqlDataAdapter.Fill`), or in a reader (if you use `ExecuteReader`).

Comment: Please check my edited code and let me know what i need to change ?! I am not able to call SqlDataAdapter.Fill

Answer (score 2):

SQLite uses a subset of the SQL-92 language, so most of the basics are the same as in other SQL environments. `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` clauses all work mostly like you'd expect.

Documentation on the syntax supported can be found here: [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Answer (score 1):

Number of time error appears is given by something like this...

```
select sum((Length(message) - length(replace(message,'error',''))) / length('error')) from 
from database where
message like '%error%'
```